# IOS or Mac WebGL2 support for Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: ios, macos, google-chrome, firefox, webgl2

I have found the webGL2 enable option of Safari.
But webGL2 still doesn't work on Chrome and Firefox on Mac or IOS?
Is there any option to enable webGL2?

Comment: You will almost certainly get more traction on [apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.SE](https://superuser.com/) instead of stackoverflow.SE.